# []byte(string) vs []byte(*string)

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, slice

I'm curious as why Go doesn't provide a `[]byte(*string)` method. From a performance perspective, wouldn't `[]byte(string)` make a copy of the input argument and add more cost (though this seems odd since strings are immutable, why copy them)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373634/how-expensive-is-bytestring

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`[]byte("something")` is not a function (or method) call, it's a type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions).

The type conversion "itself" does not copy the value. Converting a `string` to a `[]byte` however does, and it needs to, because the result byte slice is *mutable*, and if a copy would not be made, you could modify / alter the `string` value (the content of the `string`) which is *immutable*, it must be as the [Spec: String types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) section dictates:

> Strings are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the contents of a string.

Note that there are few cases when `string` <=> `[]byte` conversion does not make a copy as it is optimized "away" by the compiler. These are rare and "hard coded" cases when there is proof an immutable `string` cannot / will not end up modified.

Such an example is looking up a value from a map where the key type is `string`, and you index the map with a `[]byte`, converted to `string` of course ([source](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3512)):

```
key := []byte("some key")

var m map[string]T
// ...
v, ok := m[string(key)]  // Copying key here is optimized away
```

Another optimization is when ranging over the bytes of a `string` that is explicitly converted to a byte slice:

```
s := "something"
for i, v := range []byte(s) { // Copying s is optimized away
    // ...
}
```

(Note that without the conversion the `for range` would iterate over the `rune`s of the string and not over its UTF8-encoded bytes.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I forgot the fact that a byte slice is mutable, so a copy is needed.  Thanks

Comment: FYI, there is a feature request for immutable byte array https://github.com/golang/go/issues/2205

Answer (score 5):

> I'm curious as why Golang doesn't provide a []byte(*string) method.

Because it doesn't make sense.

A pointer (to any type) cannot be represented (in any obviously meaningful way) as a `[]byte`.

> From a performance perspective, wouldn't []byte(string) make a copy of the input argument and add more cost (though this seems odd since strings are immutable, why copy them)?

Converting from `[]byte` to `string` (and vice versa) does involve a copy, because strings are immutable, but byte arrays are not.

However, using a pointer wouldn't solve that problem.