# Does accessing elements of string as byte perform conversion?

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, rune

In Go, to access elements of a `string`, we can write:

```
str := "text"
for i, c := range str {
  // str[i] is of type byte
  // c is of type rune
}
```

When accessing `str[i]` does Go perform a conversion from `rune` to `byte`? I would guess the answer is yes, but I am not sure. If so, then, which one of the following methods are better performance-wise? Is one preferred over another (in terms of best practice, for example)?

```
str := "large text"
for i := range str {
  // use str[i]
}
```

or

```
str := "large text"
str2 := []byte(str)
for _, s := range str2 {
  // use s
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Which one of the following methods are better performance-wise?*

Definitely not this.

```
str := "large text"
str2 := []byte(str)
for _, s := range str2 {
  // use s
}
```

Strings are immutable. `[]byte` is mutable. That means `[]byte(str)` makes a copy. So the above will copy the entire string. I've found being unaware of when strings are copied to be a major source of performance problems for large strings.

If `str2` is never altered, the compiler *may* optimize away the copy. For this reason, it's better to write the above like so to ensure the byte array is never altered.

```
str := "large text"
for _, s := range []byte(str) {
  // use s
}
```

That way there's no `str2` to possibly be modified later and ruin the optimization.

But this is a bad idea because it will corrupt any multi-byte characters. See below.

---

As for the byte/rune conversion, performance is not a consideration as they are not equivalent. `c` will be a rune, and `str[i]` will be a byte. If your string contains multi-byte characters, you have to use runes.

For example...

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str := "snow ☃ man"
    for i, c := range str {
        fmt.Printf("c:%c str[i]:%c\n", c, str[i])
    }
}

$ go run ~/tmp/test.go
c:s str[i]:s
c:n str[i]:n
c:o str[i]:o
c:w str[i]:w
c:  str[i]: 
c:☃ str[i]:â
c:  str[i]: 
c:m str[i]:m
c:a str[i]:a
c:n str[i]:n
```

Note that using `str[i]` corrupts the multi-byte Unicode snowman, it only contains the first byte of the multi-byte character.

There's no performance difference anyway as `range str` already must do the work to go character-by-character, not byte by byte.

Comment: The first part about []byte/string is not true per se. The compiler performs escape analysis and some extra optimizations around []byte/string to avoid some allocations. If you compile your first snippet with '-gcflags "-m -m"' you will see that this case won't allocate since str2 is only used in the loop and does not escape.

Comment: @nussjustin Yeah. Writing it as `for ... range []byte(str)` makes the optimization more obvious.

Comment: In general converting `string` to `[]byte` does make a copy, but if used in a `for ... range`, it won't. It is optimized away by the compiler. For details see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344).

Answer (score 3):

`string` values in Go store the UTF-8 encoded bytes of the text, not its characters or `rune`s.

[Indexing](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) a `string` indexes its bytes: `str[i]` is of type `byte` (or `uint8`, its an alias). Also a `string` is in effect a read-only slice of bytes (with some syntactic sugar). Indexing a `string` does not require converting it to a slice.

When you use `for ... range` on a `string`, that iterates over the `rune`s of the `string`, not its bytes!

So if you want to iterate over the `runes` (characters), you must use a `for ... range` but without a conversion to `[]byte`, as the first form will not work with `string` values containing multi(UTF-8)-byte characters. 
The [spec allows you](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) to `for ... range` on a `string` value, and the 1st iteration value will be the byte-index of the current character, the 2nd value will be the current character value of type `rune` (which is an alias to `int32`):

> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

Simple example:

```
s := "Hi 世界"
for i, c := range s {
    fmt.Printf("Char pos: %d, Char: %c\n", i, c)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PzMrUDzixf)):

```
Char pos: 0, Char: H
Char pos: 1, Char: i
Char pos: 2, Char:  
Char pos: 3, Char: 世
Char pos: 6, Char: 界
```

Must read blog post for you:

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

---

Note: If you must iterate over the *bytes* of a `string` (and not its characters), using a `for ... range` with a converted `string` like your second example does not make a copy, it's optimized away. For details, see [golang: []byte(string) vs []byte(*string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470284/golang-bytestring-vs-bytestring/43470344#43470344).

Comment: Ooops, I had it backwards