# Access random rune element of string without using for ... range

Tags: string, go, type-conversion, byte, rune

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487910/does-accessing-elements-of-string-as-byte-perform-conversion) question and the answers increased my understanding, but they didn't solve the actual problem I had. So, I will try to ask a similar but different question as follows.

Suppose that I want to access random `rune` element of a `string`. One way is:

```
func RuneElement(str string, idx int) rune {
  var ret rune
  for i, c := range str {
    if i == idx {
      return c
    }
  }
  return ret // out of range -> proper handling is needed
}
```

What if I want to call such a function a lot of times? I guess what I am looking for is like an operator/function like `str[i]` (which returns a `byte`) that return the `rune` element at `i`-th position. Why this element can be accessed using `for ... range` but not through a funtcion like `str.At(i)` for example?

Comment: If you don't want to convert a `string` to `[]rune` in every call, you need to use `[]rune`

Comment: @JimB But, my input is a string and I try to avoid conversion of `string` to `[]rune`

Comment: My point is that you need to convert a `string` to a `[]rune` in order to index it as such. If you don't want to repeatedly convert the `string`, then use a `[]rune` as the argument type, and convert it once.

Comment: Or are you simply looking for: https://play.golang.org/p/RdH7oMCHIZ?

Comment: @JimB Yes, that is what I am looking for, but without conversion from `string` to `[]rune`. It seems that it's not possible though because of the way `string` is designed as @icza mentions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44527543/2229960)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string` values in Go store the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of the text. This is a design decision that has been made and it won't change.

If you want to efficiently get a `rune` from it at an arbitrary index, you have to decode the bytes, you can't do anything about that (the `for ... range` does this decoding). There is no "shortcut". The chosen representation just doesn't provide this out of the box.

If you have to do this frequently / many times, you should change your input and not use `string` but a `[]rune`, as it's a slice and can be efficiently indexed. `string` in Go is not `[]rune`. `string` in Go is effectively a read-only `[]byte` (UTF-8). Period.

If you can't change the input type, you may build an internal cache mapped from `string` to its `[]rune`:

```
var cache = map[string][]rune{}

func RuneAt(s string, idx int) rune {
    rs := cache[s]
    if rs == nil {
        rs = []rune(s)
        cache[s] = []rune(s)
    }
    if idx >= len(rs) {
        return 0
    }
    return rs[idx]
}
```

It depends on case whether this is worth it: if `RuneAt()` is called with a small set of `string`s, this may improve performance a lot. If the passed strings are more-or-less unique, this will result in worse performance and a lot of memory usage. Also this implementation is not safe for concurrent use.

Comment: Just curious what may be the rationale behind the design decision.

Comment: @AlexanderItes I guess the authors thought the advantages outweight the disadvantages. Some operations just don't care about the representation (e.g. equality check), other operations that require runes: decoding runes from UTF-8 bytes is faster than you think, and very often the UTF-8 representation is needed in the end (e.g. when transmitting textual data), so having that stored simplifies and makes such operations faster.