# Immutable string and pointer address

Tags: string, go, immutability

In Go [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) is written:

> Strings are immutable: once created, it is impossible to change the
>   contents of a string.

I have following code:

```
str := "hello"
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&str) // 0x1040c128
fmt.Printf("%v\n",str) // hello
ptr := &str
*ptr = "world"
fmt.Printf("%p\n",&str) // 0x1040c128
fmt.Printf("%v\n",str) // world
```

I would have expected `&str` address was changed after `*ptr = "world"`. As it would happen with Java, where we reassign String references.

What is 'immutability' here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`string` *values* are immutable.

`str` is not a `string` value. It's a *variable* (of `string` type). And values of variables may be changed, that's what you'd expect from any programming language.

`"hello"` is a `string` value, and this is what is immutable. `"world"` is another `string` value, and when you assign `"world"` to `str`, you just assign another, different value to the `str` variable. It doesn't matter if you're doing it directly to `str`, or via a pointer. You're just changing the value of the variable denoted by `str`.

Immutable means you cannot take the `string` value `"world"`, and change its second character for example. If you have a function for example which receives a `string` argument, whatever it receives (e.g. `"hello"`), you can be sure it will always remain the same. No matter when / how you print this `string` value, it will always be `"hello"`.

A `string` value is a struct value under the hood, represented by the [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StringHeader) type:

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

It basically stores a data pointer (to the byte array holding the UTF-8 encoded value of the text), and the byte-length of the `string` value. The data array and its length are not exposed to you, so you can't modify them. This is one element of making sure that `string` values are immutable. Another element is that although `string` values can be indexed (which indexes its bytes), you can not assign new values to the index expressions. E.g. it is valid to use the value `"abc"[0]`, but it is invalid to assign a new value to it like `"abc"[0] = 'x'`. Similarly, you cannot take the address of an index expression indexing a `string` value (else you could modify the pointed value and thus indirectly the `string` value).

This is what the [language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) guarantees. Note that there are certain ways to still change `string` values, e.g. using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), but this falls outside the guarantees of the spec:

> Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of Go programs.
>
> Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines.

The "moment" you import package `unsafe`, you'll lose any guarantees and safety provided by the language spec, and from there on you can't complain for anything. But *without* using these "special" means, it cannot happen that a `string` value gets altered.

Read the blog post [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings) for how `string` is implemented and works in Go.

See related questions:

[What is the difference between the string and []byte in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625959/what-is-the-difference-between-the-string-and-byte-in-go/32626057#32626057)

[What are the possible consequences of using unsafe conversion from []byte to string in go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952378/what-are-the-possible-consequences-of-using-unsafe-conversion-from-byte-to-str/33953027#33953027)

Comment: To expand, a "string" variable is fundamentally a modified slice header.  The string header itself is at some location in memory (`0x1040c128` in your example), and that location in memory holds two values, a pointer to an underlying array and the size of the string (unlike slices, strings don't have a "capacity" value, because, being immutable, their capacity always equals their length).  When you assign to a string variable, you're changing the value of _the pointer stored within that header_.  The address of the header itself does not change.

Comment: I'd also add that [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices) and [this](https://blog.golang.org/strings) (in that order) are must-reads for any baby gopher. ;-)