# Mutate a string in Golang?

Tags: string, pointers, go

For testing purposes, I'm trying to mock the [Rows.Scan](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Scan) method from the `database/sql` library. The signature looks like this:

```golang
func (r *Rows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
```

Many examples of how to use this show that you pass a pointer to a string (for example) to the Scan method and it will assign the value through the pointer.

```golang
var name string
rows.Scan(&name)
```

I've been trying to recreate something similar for my own understanding and eventually for mocking but it is not working.

```
func MockScan(args ...interface{}) {
    var s2 string
    fmt.Println(args[0])
    args[0] = &s2
    fmt.Println(args[0])
}

func main() {
    var s1 string
    fmt.Println(&s1)
    MockScan(&s1)
    fmt.Println(&s1)
}
```

Results in:

```
0xc000012950
0xc000012950
0xc000012960
0xc000012950
```

Where my initial string never takes on its new value. I understand that strings are immutable (although my true understanding of this concept is a little shakey) but somehow the actual `Rows.Scan` method manages to mutate the string.

Comment: See possible duplicates: [Immutable string and pointer address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352449/immutable-string-and-pointer-address/47352588#47352588); and [Immutability of string and concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249918/immutability-of-string-and-concurrency/51250031#51250031)

Comment: `&s1` is a pointer to the local variable `s1`. Every time you do `&s1` you're going to get the same address because it's the same variable you're taking the address of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`args[0] = &s2`

This does nothing outside of `MockScan`. You're changing what `args[0]` points to, you're not changing *the thing pointed to by `args[0]`*.

You want to do something like

```
func MockScan(args ...interface{}) {
    // In real life, there would be some logic here to figure out what
    // kind of pointer we're dealing with, or some error handling to
    // handle the case where the user didn't pass a *string
    dst := args[0].(*string)
    *dst = "A new value"
}

func main() {
    var s1 string = "An old value"
    fmt.Println(s1)
    MockScan(&s1)
    fmt.Println(s1)
}
```

Note that if we printed `&s1` in main before and after the call, it *still wouldn't change*. It's still the same variable, it's still at the same address. We've passed a pointer, `&s1` into `MockScan`, so that `MockScan` can use that pointer to write a value into `s1`.

Comment: Worth mentioning here that a [Type Assertion](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) was used to make sure we access args[0] as a string pointer.

Comment: Natski, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) for more background—it's a crucial thing to grasp.

Comment: Thank you for your responses and answer. I was following this blog post which does the same thing but with structs (it just seems to work): https://goinbigdata.com/golang-pass-by-pointer-vs-pass-by-value/. Am I correct to assume that structs and strings are behaving differently between my example and the blog post?

Comment: @natsuki_2002 regarding the linked post, if you do `p = &Person{firstName: "Bob"}` you get the same outcome as with the string pointer, so in this respect there's no difference between structs and strings. However the *selector* expression `s.f` is something different, here `s` can be a pointer to a struct and the language will still allow you to access the field `f` without having to first dereference the pointer, e.g. you don't have to do `(*s).f`, that's done automatically. [more here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)